# ReflectionException Laravel Console Command

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces

I'm trying to perform a Curl method into a Laravel console command, but I'm getting `ReflectionException`. I've already tried `composer update && composer dump-autoload` but the problem persists.

My code is like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Ixudra\Curl\Facades\Curl;

class IndexOrders extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'my:command';
    protected $description = 'Description';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        Curl::doSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: Basically `Curl Class not Found`. Sorry, I'm stuck on my phone now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the facade directly, you need to ensure that you have

```
Ixudra\Curl\CurlServiceProvider::class,
```

in your config/app.php providers array

and that you have

```
'Curl'          => Ixudra\Curl\Facades\Curl::class,
```

in your config/app.php aliases array

Comment: That's it. I had the lib in other project and bringing to another one, forget to add the alias. Thanks!